# Cassandra Datastax Optimal PoolingOptions

Tags: spring, cassandra, datastax, spring-data-cassandra

I'm Working on a spring/java webapp using cassandra as backend; the app would be used by potentially hundreds of customers simultaneously.

I see that default Cluster PoolingOptions connection pool settings (With protocol v3) are:

```
LOCAL hosts: core = max = 1
REMOTE hosts: core = max = 1
```

And default maxRequestsPerConnection setting (With protocol v3) is:

```
1024 for LOCAL hosts, and 256 for REMOTE hosts.
```

Will these default settings be sufficient to fulfill our usage requirements?

If not, What poolingoptions can I start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the default `PoolingOptions`.  It should not really be touched unless you have a good reason.

Note that the configuration is *per host*, not for the entire cluster.

Also, by default cassandra only processes 128 native transport requests at a time ([native_transport_max_threads](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html#reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__native_transport_max_threads)), so configuring `PoolingOptions` to handle more than 1024 requests per connection has low utility.

Finally, during benchmarking and high throughput scenarios with a small number of nodes, increasing the number of connections per host to something like 8 can show some improvement in throughput, but as you add more C* hosts that improvement becomes marginal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andy. As suggested we would go with default settings and will do the tweaking later as needed. Also stumbled upon this doc from datastax, may be helpful to someone http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/pooling/.