# Cassandra Datastax and Java - best way to set up connection

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I'm researching the best way to make a connection from my Java to Cassandra and found some amount of examples how to do that. I'm doing some kind of chat application on my localhost (will allow to create new messages, update them or delete), but also I would like to research best practice. Can anybody help me to choose the best one solution?

The first one example is Spark 1.6:

```
public static JavaSparkContext getCassandraConnector(){
         SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
         conf.setAppName("Chat");
         conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
         conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
         conf.set("spark.rpc.netty.dispatcher.numThreads","2");
         conf.setMaster("local[2]");

         JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
         return sc;
    }
```

So, I also got an example for Spark 2.x where the builder will automatically reuse an existing SparkContext if one exists and create a SparkContext if it does not exist. Configuration options set in the builder are automatically propagated over to Spark and Hadoop during I/O.

```
public static SparkSession getSparkSession(){
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("Chat")
        .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true")
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/file:C:/temp")
        .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
        .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
        .master("local[2]")
        .getOrCreate();
    return sparkSession;
}
```

I also researched Pooling Options but found examples one for Session, like:

```
public static Session getPoolSession(){
    PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
    poolingOptions
    .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL,  4)
    .setMaxConnectionsPerHost( HostDistance.LOCAL, 10)
    .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 32768)
    .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2000)
    .setHeartbeatIntervalSeconds(120);

    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
        .addContactPoints("127.0.0.1")
        .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
        .build();

    Session session = cluster.connect("chat");
    return session;
    }
```

So I wonder, what is the most efficient way to make a connection (I'm going to execute single statements and PreparedStatements as well). I think that the first way from Spark 1.6 was no as good as 2.x, but what about Pooling Option examples for 2.x (I'm not 100% sure if this is already included to SparkSession)?
I found related questions, but there is no enough information to me: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148056/cassandra-datastax-optimal-poolingoption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148056/cassandra-datastax-optimal-poolingoptions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to connect to cassandra using spark or just java to Cassandra connection?

Spark is used most of the time for analytical workflows, and single insert/update statements is not a use case for it.

I suggest using regular datastax java driver:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver-dse/1.1/

As answered in pooling options question, you don't need to touch these parameters and default values should do the work. Here's is a explanation of how it works:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.2/com/datastax/driver/core/PoolingOptions.html

Comment: @nervsv I got a REST application Angular JS - Java - Cassandra DB. I'm just researching the best way to make a connection between Java and Cassandra (get messages, post message, etc)